# Publishing WCF/EF Application not working

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, iis

I'm trying to publish a WCF application on the same machine as have developed the app in VS2010 but I keep getting the error below when accessing the db. The database is MySQL and I'm using MySQL connector 6.3.6 and EF4. I think it is some sort of permissions issue since I can see the data for the table when viewing through VS but when I try to publish from VS to IIS, I get this error when accessing the app through a browser.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks again.

This call is working and returns the collections available which includes one table newtables:

http://localhost/WcfService1/WcfDataService1.svc

Here is the how I'm trying to access the table:

http://localhost/WcfService1/WcfDataService1.svc/newtables

Here is the error returned:

```
<error>
<code/>
<message xml:lang="en-US">An error occurred while processing this request.</message>
<innererror>
<message>
Schema specified is not valid. Errors: Model1.ssdl(2,84) : error 0002: Request failed.
</message>
<type>System.Data.MetadataException</type>
<stacktrace>
at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection.Loader.LoadItems(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 sourceFilePaths) at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection.Init(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 filePaths, Boolean throwOnError, DbProviderManifest& providerManifest, DbProviderFactory& providerFactory, String& providerManifestToken, Memoizer`2& cachedCTypeFunction) at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection..ctor(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 filePaths) at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.StoreMetadataEntry.LoadStoreCollection(EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection, MetadataArtifactLoader loader) at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.LoadItemCollection[T](IItemCollectionLoader`1 itemCollectionLoader, T entry) at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.GetOrCreateStoreAndMappingItemCollections(String cacheKey, MetadataArtifactLoader loader, EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection, Object& entryToken) at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.LoadStoreItemCollections(MetadataWorkspace workspace, DbConnection storeConnection, DbProviderFactory factory, DbConnectionOptions connectionOptions, EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection, MetadataArtifactLoader artifactLoader) at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.GetMetadataWorkspace(Boolean initializeAllCollections) at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.InitializeMetadata(DbConnection newConnection, DbConnection originalConnection, Boolean closeOriginalConnectionOnFailure) at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open() at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection() at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption) at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator() at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetEnumeratorInternal() at System.Data.Services.WebUtil.GetRequestEnumerator(IEnumerable enumerable) at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.SerializeResponseBody(RequestDescription description, IDataService dataService) at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.HandleRequest()
</stacktrace>
</innererror>
</error>
```